# How do I prevent django from accessing a database during a test?

Tags: python, django, database, testing

I'm trying to write a django health check for a cloud app to determine if the server is still healthy.

One of the checks determines if the database is still accessible. And I want to test if this works, so I'm writing a django test script to verify this.

Except django is really good at keeping a database connection.

Things which haven't worked:

Using override settings:

```
@override_settings(DATABASES={})
def test_dead_database(self):
```

Popping the default database settings:

```
    from django.conf import settings
    old_db_eng = settings.DATABASES.pop('default')
```

But Django keeps the database alive!

How can I *force* the django database to go away within a test?

---

edit: this is made more difficult as the test suite checks against a number of database engines - so I'd prefer a django focused solution.

Comment: The test script should not be connecting to the production database. It should connect to a temporary database that you can bring down for the purpose of this test.

Comment: Its not connected to the production database this is for being run in travis-ci test suite. However, I still cannot automatically get the connection to the database to die.